# Install python-pyparsing 1.4.2-1.1_all.deb on debian etch with apt-get

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pyparsing

I am trying to install `python-pyparsing` onto my `debian etch` but running into issues when I run `sudo apt-get install python-pyparsing_1.4.2-1.1_all.deb`. Seems to give me this error here

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
W: Couldn't stat source package list http://archive.debian.org etch/main Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.debian.org_debian_dists_etch_main_binary-i386_Packages) -stat (2 No such file or directory)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Couldn't find package python-pyparsing_1.4.2-1.1_all.deb
```

I've run apt-get update but it tells me again same error and then

```
E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**UPDATE**

I now have `apt-get install -f` trying to install my `python-pyparsing_1.4.2-1.1_all.deb` file and it reads back:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
E: Couldn't find package python-pyparsing_1.4.2-1.1_all.deb
```

I'm not getting the run `apt-get update` anymore. Is there a directory I need to have this in? I have it inside my /mnt/hgfs/ directory at this time.

Any help is greatly appreciated on how to get `pyparsing` installed for this `debian`

Comment: [How to install local .deb packages with apt-get](http://superuser.com/q/196864/126558), [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/q/40779/50786)

Comment: @LevLevitsky I have tried both of these resources and still get the above errors, but thanks :)

Comment: @urbanrunic can you post the full error code?. may be there might be the problem with mirror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the *package* is `python-pyparsing`. You are using the package file name, which is composed of the package name, version, and architecture, with a `.deb` extension to boot.

The correct command line is

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyparsing
```

The package toolchain takes care of finding a suitable version for your architecture, and downloading it from a suitable repository. (`apt-cache policy python-pyparsing` will tell you which versions are available.)

If you require this specific version, use

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyparsing=1.4.2-1.1
```

provided it is available from one of the Apt sources you have configured.

(If you have a `deb` file which you have downloaded, you can install that with `dpkg`:

```
sudo dpkg -i path/to/python-pyparsing_1.4.2-1.1_all.deb
```

but you should normally never need to do this. `dpkg` doesn't download missing dependencies or do much anything you don't specifically ask it to.)

Comment: thanks, I have tried this quite a few times. I did download the `.deb` from a mirror. Which I have tried a few different mirrors thinking that the file may be corrupt which isn't the case. I'm still getting the `"No such file or directory"`.

Comment: Which command gives you this error? What is the full error message?

Comment: The command I am running is `sudo dpkg -i python-pyparsing`  and the error is this: `dpkg: error processing python-pyparsing (--install): cannot access archive: No such file or directory Errors were encountered while processing: python-pyparsing`

Comment: No, for `dpkg` you need the actual file name.

Comment: Ok and when I run `sudo dpkg -i python-pyparsing_1.4.2-1.1_all.deb` I get this error: `dpkg-deb (subprocess): failed to exec tar: Too many levels of symbolic links dpkg-deb: subprocess tar returned error exit status 2 dpkg: error processing python-pyparsing_1.4.2-1.1_all.deb (--install): subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2 Errors were encountered while processing: python-pyparsing_1.4.2-1.1_all.deb`

Comment: Googling this error message suggests `star` as the culprit. If it's not that, is your `tar` otherwise boken somehow? `dpkg` needs it. What's the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/tar` and `type tar` for you?

Comment: I was just reading about `star`...well the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/tar` is `/lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 2013-10-25 10:21 /usr/bin/tar -> tar` and the output of `type tar` is `tar is /bin/tar`

Comment: Looks like your `/usr/bin/tar` is indeed a symlink to itself. How would you wind up with that? Anyway, remove it and try again. Hopefully `/bin/tar` is healthy. If not, you're pretty hosed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45742/discussion-between-tripleee-and-urbanrunic)

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to install Pyparsing for development purposes (that is, you're writing a program that uses Pyparsing, rather than just trying to install another deb that has Pyparsing as a dependency), you shouldn't use your distribution's package manager.

Instead, create a virtualenv (http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) to develop your application, and use the supplied `distribute` dependency management system.

Virtualenvs are self-contained Python environments that don't have access to any of the Python modules you have installed system-wide (and can even, if you want, use a different version of Python than your system). Instead, they download and install (in themselves) all the dependencies of the programs/libs you want to run within them.

The advantages to that approach are the following:

- You're not limited to the libs and versions present in your distribution's package manager (which are often outdated -- for example, Pyparsing is currently at version 2.0.1, unlike Debian's 1.4.2).
- You can ensure that the dependencies of *your* program/lib are correctly documented in its `setup.py`, instead of working by sheer luck because you have something installed system-wide that you forgot about 6 months ago.
- Furthermore, those will be downloaded and installed automatically with one line: `python setup.py install`, which greatly simplifies your program's installation and deployment.
- Yes, you *should* use a virtualenv in your production environment too. Why? Because if you're running different programs with different sets (and versions) of dependencies in the same environment (that is, your computer's actual Python installation), installing a new version of a lib because program A requires it might break program B which relies on an old version.
- Your program/lib's dependency management will work in any OS or distro (even Windows) without any extra effort.
- It's easy to *uninstall* the crappy libraries that you tried once and decided weren't good for your project: if `pip uninstall xxxx` doesn't work, just delete the virtualenv and recreate it -- it is, after all, only one line to get all your deps back.

Comment: I totally agree with your answer BUT this team does not use `virtualenvs` so I'm treading in new waters. I can't get pip to install on this old version of debian with out syntax errors. Thanks for that, but unfortunately I can't go that route.

Comment: What version of Python are you running? Pip should run fine with 2.6 and later, and if you're stuck with 2.4 or 2.5 you can go with older versions (1.1 and 1.3.1 respectively).

Comment: they are running 2.4.4, I install `PIP` 1.3.1 but that is giving syntax errors.

Comment: You need 1.1 -- 1.3.1 is for Python 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

Just open Ubuntu software centre, reinstall `ubuntu-extras-keyring` and then run `sudo apt-get update` from terminal.

Comment: I'm not familiar and can't find how you reinstall `ubuntu-extras-keyring` do you have a link to how this is done? Thanks!